# I want to make a shard status command which tells the status for each shard I made in discord.js?

Tags: discord.js

I am a bot developer using javascript to code discord bots. I want to create a shard status command where it shows the status for each of the shards. I have no idea how to do it, but If you guys could help me, I would appreciate you.

I am at school so I might not be able to reply fast enough. So please bear with me!

Comment: What is your discord.js version?

Comment: Latest: [discord.js package](https://npmjs.com/package/discord.js) sorry for the late reply

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `broadcastEval()`. For example:

```js
// For each shard, get the shard ID and the number of guilds it owns
let values = await client.shard.broadcastEval(`
    [
        this.shard.id,
        this.guilds.size
    ]
`);
// Make a final string which will be sent in the channel
let finalString = "**SHARD STATUS**\n\n";
// For each shard data
values.forEach((value) => {
    // Add the shard infos to the final string
    finalString += "• SHARD #"+value[0]+" | ServerCount: "+value[1]+"\n";
});
// Send the final string in the channel
message.channel.send(finalString);
```

This will send something like:

**SHARD STATUS**

- SHARD #0 | ServerCount: 98
- SHARD #1 | ServerCount: 95
- SHARD #2 | ServerCount: 97

Note you can't access to veritable shard **status** like "reconnecting", or "resuming" using Discord.js v11. For this, ou need to use the [master branch](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js).

Comment: Hi, when I'm running this, it returns me an error: `TypeError: SHARDING_INVALID_EVAL_BROADCAST`. I'm running this on the <client>.on('ready') event.

Answer (score 0):

For d.js v13 you can do something like:

```
client.shard.broadcastEval(client => [client.shard.ids, client.ws.status, client.ws.ping, client.guilds.cache.size])
.then((results) =>{
    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(`‍ Bot Shards (${interaction.client.shard.count})`)
        .setColor('#ccd6dd')
        .setTimestamp();
    
    results.map((data) => {
        embed.addField(` Shard ${data[0]}`, `**Status:** ${data[1]}\n**Ping:** ${data[2]}ms\n**Guilds:** ${data[3]}`, false)
    });
    interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed] });
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    interaction.reply(`❌ Error.`);
});
```

Remember to change `interaction.reply` to something equivalent